# change lokalized storyboards

Tags: ios5, localization, xcode4.2, storyboard

I need localization to be independent of device (iPad) setting.

Is it possible to switch between localized storyboard in code. I found out how to change the NSUserDefaults or create new NSBundle so I can get the correct localized strings. But what if I have lokalized storyboards how should I handle that?

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load another storyboard than the default one (the main storyboard), just load it:

```
UIStoryBoard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"TheOtherStoryboard" bundle: nil];
UIViewController *rootVC = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

If you don't specify a main storyboard/NIB in your `Info.plist` file, you can also load the storyboard manually in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your application's delegate. In fact, you must do it there if you don't specify a main storyboary/NIB.

Hope that helps. :-)